# Reading data from two OpenOffice Calc columns

Tags: python

I have an OpenOffice calc with a long table of data inside, and I need to import the numbers in one of the columns as a vector in Python, and the numbers in the adjacent columns as another vector, so that I can use them for polynomial interpolation later.

Is there any easy way to do this? I'm a beginner in Python and haven't been able to solve my problem with online tutorials, but it seems it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used python's `csv` library to read and manipulate data from spreadsheets (you would have to convert the spreadsheet to a csv). [Check the manual here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), specifically the class `csv.DictReader`.

In the sample snippet, just change the `for row in reader:` loop to save a row as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the openpyxl http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html

One of the possible solutions:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='your_file', read_only=True)  #  change your_file
    ws = wb['dump_newssources'] #  specify the sheet in the file    
    for element in ws.iter_rows():
        for i, cell in enumerate(element):
            if(i == 0): #  value in the first cell of the row
                pass  # do something
            elif(i == 1): #  value in the second cell of the row
                pass #  do something
```